# Objective-C NSMutableArray not saving objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm learning Objective-C (having come from Java) and I'm am attempting to program a small Cocoa app on OSX. I am thinking with my Java hat on and that's probably why this isn't working. Basically I am trying to get an object of type Car added to an NSMutableArray on a button click but although the rest of the code seems to work, nothing is being saved to the array. I can't figure out why - help is appreciated. Here's the code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Car.h"
#import "PileInterface.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate

PileInterface *myStack;
Car *car;

//initialise Stack
-(void)stack{
myStack = [[PileInterface alloc]init];
//initialise myStack in Pileinterface
[myStack initialise];
}

  - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    //corrected code here to call the stack method above
    //initialise myStack by calling stack method
     [self stack];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (IBAction)addBtn:(NSButton *)sender {
    car = [[Car alloc]init];
    NSString *licence = [_txtField1 stringValue];
    NSString *model = [_txtField2 stringValue];
    NSString *colour = [_txtField3 stringValue];

    if ([myStack isFull] == false) {
        // add Car objects to car
        //set licence
        [car setLicence:licence];
        // set model
        [car setModel:model];
        //set colour
        [car setColour:colour];

        //add to stack
        [myStack push:car];
        //append to textarea
        NSString *message = licence;
        [_txtArea setStringValue:message];
        [_txtField2 setIntegerValue:[myStack size]];

    } else {
        NSString *message2 = @"Rejected. There are more than 4 cars currently for recycling!";
        [_txtArea insertText:message2];
    }


}
@end
```

Effectively Car is the object I want to get into myStack (which is a stack inside PileInterface, which also contains the NSMutableArray)

PileInterface implementation code here:

```
#import "PileInterface.h"

@implementation PileInterface

//arraylist of objects
NSMutableArray *list;

//initialise array
-(void)initialise{
    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

-(void) push:(id) o{
    [list insertObject:o atIndex:0];
}

-(id) pop{
    if ([list count] > 0) {
        NSObject *temp =[list objectAtIndex:0];
        [list removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        return temp;

    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

-(BOOL) isEmpty{
    if ([list count] == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

-(int) size{
    return (int)[list count];
}

-(BOOL) isFull{
    if ([list count] > 4) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@end
```

Help Appreciated!

Comment: I don't see `stack`  being called anywhere, so probably your pile instance is not allocated/initialized. Better put that code in the constructor of the constructor anyway. Also, your stack implementation is unnecessarily inefficient (not gonna matter a lot for 4 elements, though): you could just push to the **end** of the `NSMutableArray` using `addObject:`, that should generally faster. Also, `if (condition) return true; else return false;` could (and should) be simplified to `return condition;` for readability purposes.

Comment: Terrific thank you. I wasn't initialising the stack method (which in turn would instantiate PileInterface) and then I wasn't initialising the NSMutable array in PileInterface either. Sorted with two extra lines of code! Thanks for the other tips also.

Comment: Unlike Java, when you use a null pointer in Objective-C it will often silently ignore it and go merrily on its way.  When "the machine ate my homework" the first suspect is always an uninitialized pointer.